# Recuperando os values do meu form

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Estou tentando recuperar os values de um form. Essa é forma correta de recupera-los para passarpra minha DAL?

```
<div id="myModal_Veiculos" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <form id="Cad_Veiculos">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
            <h3>Cadasto de Clientes</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
                <label>Modelo </label><input type="text" name="modelo" id="modelo" />
                <label>Placa </label><input type="text" id="placa" name="placa" />
                <label>Quilometragem </label><input type="text" id="quilometragem" name="quilometragem" />
                <label>Cor </label><input type="text" name="cor" id="cor" />
                <label>Tipo </label><input type="text" name="tipo" id="tipo" />
                <label>Ano </label><input type="text" name="ano" id="ano" />
                <label>Chassi </label><input type="text" name="chassi" id="chassi" />
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Fechar</button>
            <Button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="button1_cad_veiculo">Salvar</Button>
        </div>
        </form>
    </div>
```

Recuperando os values do form

```
protected void button1_cad_veiculo(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Veiculo vl = new Veiculo();

    vl.Modelo1 = Request.Form["modelo"];
    vl.Quilometragem1 = Request.Form["quilometragem"];
    vl.Placa = Request.Form["placa"];
    vl.Cor = Request.Form["cor"];
    vl.Chassi = Request.Form["chassi"];
    vl.Tipo = Request.Form["tipo"];

    VeiculoDAL.cadastra(vl);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Recuperar você até vai recuperar, o teu problema é como fazer chegar um evento nesse seu tratamento.

- Falta o runat="server" no , ou falta o endereçamento de onde você deseja chegar com o submit desse form. Ou seja o **action** e o **method**
- Falta o runat="server" no button, ou troque para input submit ou Button do ASP.NET, ou para o type="submit" com o onserverclick="event".

Você pode tentar colocar esse teu modal, que não tem **runat="server"**, dentro de um UserControl.

No teu Visual Studio cria um novo arquivo do tipo Web User Control. Assim:
http://prntscr.com/4pmmhr

O que vai acontecer esse arquivo vai ser usado como se fosse uma tag HTML, só que diferente um pouco, procure mais sobre isso na internet, é bem util!

- Então você vai colocar todo esse código só o que está dentro do .
- Aí, você precisa criar um botão com a chamada de método que você quer, por exemplo `EnviarClick sei` lá.
- Depois disso coloca todo o seu código de "recuperação" dos valores dentro desse método.

Seu User control vai ficar assim:

Code-behind: http://prntscr.com/4pmsl5

HTML/ASP.NET: http://prntscr.com/4pmqo2

Web config: http://prntscr.com/4pms1t

P/ usá-lo: http://prntscr.com/4pmto7

Comment: O problema de usar runat, é que eu só posso usar somente um <form runat="server">, e já estou usando. Por isso estou atrás de outra forma para recuperar os values desse modal.

Comment: Bruno, tem como me da um help aqui?

Comment: Você poderia trazer estas imagens para o site? Estes links podem ficar inválidos com o tempo e resposta também ficará.

Comment: Não posso mais! meu workspace de C# foi removido da minha máquina, mas acolhi o conselho! valeu!